# Dismiss UITextField keyboard?

Tags: swift

I have multiple textfields

```
@IBOutlet var emailLogin: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var passLogin: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var emailSignUp: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var passSignUp: UITextField!
```

as of now these aren't really needed, because of how I am dismissing it by tapping anywhere on the screen, however I also want it to dismiss when I press the return key.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.emailLogin.delegate = self
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(LoginViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

First question: When I need to dismiss with only one I would set the delegate like so, but how do I handle this when I have multiple views that need to be dismissed on return key?

Also, there are two separate views, but both use the same class. Is this a problem for what I am trying to do?

From here

```
func dismissKeyboard() {

    view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

This dismisses the keyboard but only for the textfield that I set as self.

Any info is appreciated!

EDIT:
[image: I could be doing this wrong]

Comment: Don't quite understand your first question. You have to set all the textFields' delegate to `self` in order to trigger the delegate. Then in the delegate function, check the `textField` against your IBOutlet variables to have different reactions. It doesn't really matter where they are.

Comment: If I set them all as delegates. It gives me bad instruction errors.

Comment: Can you create a sample project and put it on GitHub or something?

Comment: I added an image in the OP

Comment: Are you sure `emailLogin` is connected in your storyboard?

Comment: @KurtRevis that was my first thought, but he said that the code he showed works when just emailLogin field's delegate was set, so I doubt it.

Comment: @Casey That's strange. You can try create a clean project and put just 2 textField within the VC and setup the UITextFieldDelegate like you did in this project and see if that happens too. If not it's something wrong elsewhere. If it didn't works either, you can upload the project to GitHub so others can try to fix the problem more easily.

Comment: @Zhi-WeiCai I will upload the project to GitHub and I will link for you

Comment: @KurtRevis Yes I checked and rechecked.

Comment: @Zhi-WeiCai Here is the [repository](https://github.com/FounderCasey/AppHelp)

Comment: Sorry was at work. Please check out my answer below.

Comment: In your project, I am hitting that error on the line `emailSignUp.delegate = self`. In the debugger, I can see that `emailSignUp` and `passSignUp` are `nil`. Because they are declared as [implicitly unwrapped optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID334) -- that is, using `!` -- your app crashes when they are nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to the following and it should work:

```
@IBOutlet var emailLogin: UITextField?
@IBOutlet var passLogin: UITextField?
@IBOutlet var emailSignUp: UITextField?
@IBOutlet var passSignUp: UITextField?

emailLogin?.delegate = self
passLogin?.delegate = self
emailSignUp?.delegate = self
passSignUp?.delegate = self
```

The **IBOutlets** from other class were not initialized when your `LoginViewController` loads, thus end up with unwrapping `nil` objects, which is not allowed in Swift. (You should be able to see that in your console output in Xcode.) Use optional variables will prevent that from happening.

Comment: Awesome! Working as intended! Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewControllerDelegate to handle tap outside of any textField and textView. It will dismiss keyboard when you tap on outside of textField. Put below code in your view controller:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent:event)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

You don't need to add TapGesture now to handle this.